# Why dropping columns after joining two temp views in pyspark isn't working, which however works with data frame joins?

Tags: join, pyspark, view, apache-spark-sql, drop

I need to create tempViews out of dataframes, then i need to join these tempviews and drop the duplicate columns. So I've written the code as mentioned below:

```
 Data1 = [  ("xx1",34,60),
           ("xx2",33,80),
           ("xx3",37,50) ]

dataSchema1 = StructType([
    StructField("Name",StringType(),True),
    StructField("Age",IntegerType(),True),
    StructField("Id",IntegerType(),True)
   ])

Data2 = [  (60,"M",3000.60),
           (80,"F",3300.80),
           (50,"M",5000.50) ]

dataSchema2 = StructType([
    StructField("Id",IntegerType(),True),
    StructField("Gender", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Salary", DoubleType(), True)
  ])

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Data1),schema=dataSchema1)
df1.createOrReplaceTempView('view1')

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Data2),schema=dataSchema2)
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('view2')

jDF=spark.sql("select * from view1 join view2 on view1.Id = view2.Id")
jDF.columns                 // ['Name', 'Age', 'Id', 'Id', 'Gender', 'Salary']
rjDF=jDF.drop('view2.ID')    //this function is not working
rjDF.columns                // ['Name', 'Age', 'Id', 'Id', 'Gender', 'Salary']
```

In the above code, drop column method is not working as expected, also its not throwing any error.
However, if i try to drop columns using data frames(which obviously not a preferable choice for me in my use-case), then drop method is working fine.

```
joinDF=df1.join(df2, df1.Id == df2.Id)
dropped=joinDF.drop(df2.Id)    // working absolutely fine
dropped.columns               // ['Name', 'Age', 'Id', 'Gender', 'Salary']
```

can anyone help me in understanding whats wrong with the first approach of drop a column from joined temp-views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drop` from the dataset takes `column names` or `column` itself to drop. This is `no-op` operation if schema doesn't contain `column name(s)`.

`drop` internally uses `analyzer.resolver` to check whether provided string is present in the dataframe or not. **Please note that you can't provide the sql like syntax of referring columns in the drop** If you provide the same spark will assume whole string as column name.

**`selectExpr("..")`** and `functions.expr("..")` internally uses **`sessionState.sqlParser`** to parse the sql like syntax of referring columns like `<table/view name>.<column_name>`.

try using the same with `expr` function if you wanted to use sql like syntax-

```
rjDF=jDF.drop(F.expr('view2.Id'))
```

else you vcan go with your working column based `drop`-

```
dropped=joinDF.drop(df2.Id)
```

Comment: >rjDF=jDF.drop(F.expr('view2.Id'))
this resolved my problem. Thanks a ton!